# I am getting an error while configuring the Code Igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Filename: D:\Xamp\htdocs\store\application\controllers\helloworld.php

Line Number: 7

I am configuring **Code Ignitor** and having an error while I run the localhost.Here's the code which cause error. I don't know what the issue behind this.

```
<?php
    class Helloworld extends Controller{
        function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('helloworld_model');

            $data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model-><span class="sql">getData</span>();
            $data['page_title'] = "CI Hello World App!";

            $this->load->view('helloworld_view',$data);
        }
    }
?>


========================================================================
```

Comment: why r u including html in controller file?? <span> <-- what is this??

Comment: Bad practice , remove this span statement, you want to show it, use that in your view.

Comment: Codeginter core controller  by default name CI_Controller. also please change that.

Answer (score 3):

`<span class="sql">getData</span>()` is the problem.

Perhaps you meant

```
<?php
    class Helloworld extends Controller{
        function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('helloworld_model');

            $data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model->getData(); //remove span tag
            $data['page_title'] = "CI Hello World App!";

            $this->load->view('helloworld_view',$data);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you are some mistake to about call your model , so please check below code may be helpful.

```
 <?php
        class Helloworld extends Controller{
            function index()
            { 
                $this->load->model('helloworld_model');

                $data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model->getData();
                $data['page_title'] = "CI Hello World App!";

                $this->load->view('helloworld_view',$data);
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

its useless to use the codeignitor is your using the html in controller besides of view as per the above answers you should put the html code in your views file and refer to the below code this might help:

```
<?php
    class Helloworld extends Controller{
        function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('helloworld_model');

            $data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model->getData();
            $data['page_title'] = "CI Hello World App!";

            $this->load->view('helloworld_view',['data'=>$data]);
        }
    }
?>
```

now you can use the $data to show your results in your views file like this

```
<span class="sql"><?= $data; ?></span>
```